# Using Azure for VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We have a combination of people working from home and people in an office.  The office internet has a static IP and the router allows people outside to VPN in.  We use the static IP to allow restricted access to our own Azure & AWS resources, but also to clients Azure, AWS and on-site physical hardware.

We are moving to a multi tenancy office that provides a communal internet connection for all tenants.

We'd like to set up some form of VPN in Azure that employees can connect to, authenticated by their O365 accounts (already used to log into their machines), that allows both access to our azure, but also an onward static IP that we can provide to customers who use Azure, AWS or on-site physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:  You can deploy a VPN gateway in Azure and create a site-to-site VPN with the on-prem VPN router and also another site-to-site connection between Azure and AWS, then configure P2S VPN on the same VPN gateway with AD authentication using Radius server.

I created an Azure virtual network along with gateway subnet and [virtual network gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal), gateway type as VPN and VPN type as route-based like below:

[image]

You can see public ip, this public IP address will be used to configure on-premise VPN device

Created ***local network gateway*** like below:

[image]

Created site-to-site VPN connection between virtual network gateway and on-premises VPN device like below.

In Azure portal -> type connection;

[image]

In virtual network gateway, under setting -> Add connection like below:

[image]

And try to verify the connection in local network gateway like below:

[image]

You can view the connection in the virtual network gateway.

***Reference***:

[Tutorial - Configure a BGP-enabled connection between Azure and Amazon Web Services (AWS) using the portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-aws-bgp)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-radius-password

Comment: FYI this is an off-topic question here (it has nothing to do with programming) - best not to answer these here.